How can I make sure the Elementor header is displayed correctly on Safari?
I made a website that uses Elementor. I used the theme builder to build the header and added custom javascript for the sticky effects. It works on all devices except Safari, where the header is all over the place.
I have no idea how to solve this problem. As I don't have a macbook to tweak CSS properties directly in the browser. Only an iPhone for testing purposes.
header on Safari
header on android Chrome
I disabled the javascript and figured out that this is not the problem. It has to be some CSS properties.
Here is the CSS for the header:
/* SHRINKING HEADER */

/* MOBILE MENU */
.elementor-nav-menu--toggle.elementor-element svg {
  fill: white;
}

/*==  MOBILE MENU == */

.site-logo--white.elementor-widget .elementor-widget-container a img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.main-header.page-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0 120px;
}

.shrinking-header {
  background: transparent;
  height: 160px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

.shrinking-header.shrinking-header--white {
  background: white;
}
.shrinking-header.shrinking-header--white ul li a {
  color: #444444;
}
.shrinking-header.shrinking-header--white ul li a:hover {
  color: #343434;
}
.shrinking-header.shrinking-header--white ul li a svg {
  fill: #444444;
}
.shrinking-header.shrinking-header--white ul li a:hover svg {
  fill: #343434;
}

.shrinking-header ul li a.elementor-item {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 0.9423rem + 0.2564vw, 1.25rem) !important;
}
.shrinking-header ul li a.elementor-sub-item,
.shrinking-header ul li a.elementor-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px !important;
  padding-top: 2px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

/* Shrinking logo image */

.shrinking-logo img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 88px !important;
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects img {
  height: 78px !important;
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

/* Shrinking button */

.shrinking-button a {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 0.9423rem + 0.2564vw, 1.25rem) !important;
}

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects .shrinking-button a {
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

/* Shrinking menu items */

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects ul li a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #444444 !important;
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects ul li a.elementor-sub-item {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.shrinking-header ul li a:hover svg {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) !important;
}
.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects ul li a:hover svg {
  fill: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.85) !important;
}

.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects
  .elementor-nav-menu--dropdown
  ul
  li
  a.elementor-item {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects
  .elementor-nav-menu--dropdown
  ul
  li
  a.elementor-item
  span
  svg {
  fill: #fff !important;
}

.shrinking-header svg {
  transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear !important;
}
.shrinking-header.header-shrinking-color-effects svg {
  fill: #444444 !important;
}

